# dynamically open boxes from right to left of container

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, html

I have a container div inside of which i want to dynamically create other boxes(divs) using jquery. Each new box should be placed to the left side of other open boxes. Everything works fine except for the fact that boxes open to the right side of other open boxes. Here's how i've done it so far:

```
#container{

    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:998;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    display:table-row;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.box{

    z-index:997;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width: 225px;
    position:static;
    border:1px solid #666666;
    /*next lines are added to force boxes go to bottom when minimized-cross browser solytion*/
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of appending them (i assume you are) use the [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add the new element at the start..

```
var newEl = $('<div>',{class:'box', text:'whatever..'});
$('#container').prepend( newEl );
```

demo at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/acnNe/

Comment: thanks for the answer! I was stuck trying to do it through css, although it was that easy...

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest to use [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

```
$('#container').prepend( '<div class=".box">Some content</div>' );
```

This will insert the new box as the first child of the container - before any other boxes in the container.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) That worked - i thought i could do it through css and didn't even think about looking in my jQuery code

Answer (score 1):

if you're using jQuery, you should use `$.insertBefore()` to insert new DIVs at the 'start' of a series.

http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about floating right:

```
#container{
float: right
}
```

Comment: that did the job until i added a "minimize" option to the boxes.
Then, if the container was floated right, the minimized boxes stayed on top off the container. Thanks for answering anyway!